# Preserving dimensions when slicing symbolic block matrices in sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I am using sympy (python 3.6, sympy 1.0) to facilitate the calculation of matrix-transformations in mathematical proofs.

To calculate the Schur complements it is necessary to slice a block-matrix consisting of symbolic matrices.

As directly addressing the matrix with:

```
    M[0:1,1]
```

is not working I tried *sympy.matrices.expressions.blockmatrix.blocks* Unfortunately *blocks* is messing up the dimensions of the matrices when addressing a range of blocks:

```
    from sympy import *
    n = Symbol('n')
    Aj = MatrixSymbol('Aj', n,n)

    M = BlockMatrix([[Aj, Aj],[Aj, Aj]])
    M1 = M.blocks[0:1,0:1]
    M2 = M.blocks[0,0]

    print(M1.shape)
    print(M2.shape)
```

M.blocks returns a matrix with the dimension 1,1 for the matrix M1 while the matrix M2 has the right dimension n,n.

Any suggestion how to get the right dimensions when using an interval ?

Comment: If you think `(1, 1)` is the wrong shape for `M1`, you may want to take a look at `M.shape` and see if that also looks wrong to you.

Comment: I think you might be able to just call `BlockMatrix` again on `M1` to get a block matrix, assuming you still want a block matrix there.

Comment: M.shape returns (2*n, 2*n) which is the expected result as M is a result of 4 (2x2) matrices with dimension n
BlockMatrix(M1) returns the right results, can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `blocks` returns an ImmutableMatrix object, not a BlockMatrix object. Here it is for reference:

```
def blocks(self):
    from sympy.matrices.immutable import ImmutableMatrix
    mats = self.args
    data = [[mats[i] if i == j else ZeroMatrix(mats[i].rows, mats[j].cols)
                    for j in range(len(mats))]
                    for i in range(len(mats))]
    return ImmutableMatrix(data)
```

The shape of an ImmutableMatrix object is determined by the number of symbols it contains; the structure of symbols is not taken into account. Hence, you get (1,1).

When using `M.blocks[0,0]` you access an element of the matrix, which is Aj. This is known as a MatrixSymbol, so the shape works as expected.

When using `M.blocks[0:1, 0:1]` you slice a SymPy matrix. Slicing always returns a submatrix, even if the size of the slice is 1 by 1. So you get an ImmutableMatrix with one entry, `Matrix([[Aj]])`. As said above, the shape of this thing is (1,1) since there is no recognition of the block structure.

As user2357112 suggested, converting the sliced output of blocks into a BlockMatrix causes the shape to be determined on the basis of the shape of `Aj`:

```
>>> M3 = BlockMatrix(M.blocks[0:, 0:1])
>>> M3.shape
(2*n, n)
```

It's often useful to check the type of objects that behave in unexpected way: e.g.,  `type(M1)` and `type(M2)`.